# Django con python 3.x agregar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Presenta este error

```
def agregar_producto(request,producto_id):
carro = Carro(request)#crear el carrito
producto = Producto.objects.get(id=producto_id)#identifica el producto por el id
Carro.agregar(producto=producto)#agrega el producto mediante el metodo creado en carro.py
return redirect(to='tienda')#retorna a la tienda
```

Pero no entiendo por que me pide el self? no se supone que el self hace referencia a si mismo ? o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?disculpen la verdad no entiendo, osea se que me pide que se lo pase como argumento pero el no el self no se pasa como argumento por que esta inplisito no ?

```
class Carro: #se crea el objeto
def __init__(self,request):
    self.request = request # variable para la peticion
    self.session = request.session #variable para la session
    carro = self.session.get('carro') #se iguala la session al carro 
    if not carro:
        carro = self.session['carro']={} #si no hay carro entonces se crea
    else:
        self.carro = carro #si ya hay carro puesse iguala al carro q ya estaba

def agregar(self,producto):
    if (str(producto.id) not in self.carro.keys()): #si el producto no esta en el carro
        self.carro[producto.id] = { #se agregan a al carrito los siguientes campos 
            'producto_id':producto.id,
            'nombre':producto.nombre,
            'precio':str(producto.precio),
            'cantidad':1,
            'imagen':producto.imagen.url
        }

    else:
        for key,value in self.carro.items(): #recorremos los items en el carro
            if key == str(producto.id): #vemos si corresponde la clave con alguna clave que ya este en el carrito
                value['cantidad'] = value['cantidad']+1 #en caso de que si exista el producto incrementamos solo cantidad
                break

    self.guarar_carro()
```

Comment: Parece que has metido el método `agregar()` dentro del método `__init__()` (primero de los fragmentos de código que muestras). Es decir el `def` de `agregar()` debe estar a la misma altura que el `def` de `__init__()`, y no metido hacia adentro, pues eso hace que sea un método definido dentro de init en vez de estar definido dentro de la clase.

Comment: hola , si tienes razon esta mal indentado, lo corregui y aun asi me dice esto: agregar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta para poner el código como lo tienes ahora? De paso corrige también la forma de pegarlo (debes poner una línea de ``` antes y después del fragmento de código, para no verte obligado a meter todo cuatro espacios a la derecha, que en el caso de código python puede introducir inadvertidamente errores)

Comment: listo ya actualice la pregunta bro

Comment: Ah, ya veo. `agregar()` es un método que debe ser llamado sobre un objeto, y tú lo estás llamando directamente sobre la clase. Es decir, has hecho `Carro.agregar()`. `Carro` es el nombre de la clase y no el del objeto `carro` que creaste antes. Debes usar `carro.agregar()`, de ese modo Python llamará al método en cuestión **y además** le pasará como primer parámetro el propio objeto (`carro` en este caso), cosa que no hace si lo invocas sobre la clase.

Comment: si eso mismo pense yo pero al hacerlo asi : ```carro.agregar()```  me da este error :'Carro' object has no attribute 'carro'....y alli no enteindo

Comment: En la definición de `__init__` parece que falta `self.` delante de `carro=self.session['carro']`